# Where to buy corks without grapes on them?

Tags: bottling, cork

I'm planning to bottle my first mead and went looking for corks online, but all the suppliers I'm used to only have corks with grapes on them. Minor cosmetic consideration, I realize, but is there anywhere to just buy plain corks w/o design?

Comment: search Bing or google for "plain corks". Saw some on ebay.

Answer (score 1):

If you can order this large a quantity, you can get custom corks in bulk from [WidgetCo](http://www.widgetco.com/products/wine-corks).

The [CorkStore](http://www.corkstore.com/Products/Wine-Corks) also has different styles of corks.

In general, craft stores will have corks, but you'll have a harder time finding the exact size you want for your bottles.